# Creating Resizable Image / Rectangle in iOS - Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview

I am wondering if anyone has developed a "crop" style box that a user can interact with in iOS? Specifically, I am looking for something like:

http://img192.imageshack.us/img192/8930/customcropbox.jpg

but without the actual crop functionality.

Any assistance would be great.

Answer (score 0):

somthing like below... try this way ..... u get the answer

```
 UIImage *logo_img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"google logo_transpar.png"];
UIImage *img_flag=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([logo_img CGImage],CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100))];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img_flag, nil, nil, nil);
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? Don't  just post a block of code, at least explain what it does. The question is asking for an interactive box on the screen, where is that in here?

Comment: Actually, I found an article referring to drawing a CGRect and attaching the TouchesBegin event which lead me to the answer on how to create this box as listed above. Feel free to PM me if you have a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Similar question to a couple of other threads:

[iPhone - How do you make a resizable rectangle for cropping images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971542/iphone-how-do-you-make-a-resizable-rectangle-for-cropping-images)

[Presenting an image cropping interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679937/presenting-an-image-cropping-interface)

Hope this was helpful.

Jeff it would also be useful/appreciated if you could link the article you found 'referring to drawing a CGRect and attaching the TouchesBegin event', which helped you create the box in the end.

Comment: I was actually able to find a solution for this problem. I ended up using a plain, transparent view with a border and shadow. Added some gestures to it and called it a day.