# How to get a frame for an UIImage inside another UIImage

Tags: ios, ios5, rotation, uiimage, frame

I'm trying to mask an image while im rotating it. If I try to mask without the rotation it works just fine.

So my problem is this:
[Here's the picture](http://bit.ly/OtEEFg) I need to get the inner rectangle to be cropped. But I dont have a frame for it.

I've been trying for hours to figure out how to get the frame but I fail everytime. So I ask you now.

Thanks.

edit: Sorry forgot to write that the uppercorner image is the result of cropping and masking.

Comment: try this CGRectOffset(Rect.frame, offset.x, offset.y); as in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971542/iphone-how-do-you-make-a-resizable-rectangle-for-cropping-images ques

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this?